# How to use regular expression to remove $ character in string?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to use regular expression to remove string with $ , % , # these three characters , but it seems can't remove $ and the error information shows undefined variable

How can I solve this problem?

here is my code

```
perl Remove.pl $ABC#60%


#!/usr/bin/perl

$Input = $ARGV[0];

$Input =~ s/\$|%|#//g;

print $Input;
```

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your problem is with the shell, not with the Perl code. Single quote the argument to the script:

```
perl remove.pl '$ABC#60%'
```

The shell can interpret '$ABC' as a variable name in which case the script will receive no arguments. Perl will then complain about undefined variable in substitution.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Input =~ s/[\$%#]//g;
```

ought to work

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to remove some charactor, it will be better use tr

try this:

```
perl -e '$arg = shift; $arg =~ tr/$%#//d; print $arg' '$asdf#$'
```

your code is just fine, but the parameter you pass to the program will expand in bash. you should put single quote.

try this:

```
perl Remove.pl '$ABC#60%'
```